# order with an obligation to pay stop working - Prestashop 1.7.6.0

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, e-commerce, checkout, prestashop-1.7

One of our prestashop shop is acting strange (https://www.peliniarreda.com/), "order with an obbligation to pay" button stop working at any minute with most of active payment methods (except for klarna and paypal that still works fine). Customer are unable to complete their order with bankwire, stripe, cash on delivery or amazon pay (with obviouse negative consequences on conversion rate).
We we have already tested all the proposed solutions from prestahop forums with no results.
Any idea? We are literally going crazy.

(sorry for my terrible english XD )

(update prestashop version, update modules, check configuration and override core.js with previous file version, check file permissions, nothing works)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's probably some payment module blocking the button. You could also check your browser developer console to see if there are any javascript errors. You probably did something that broke the checkout process. Start by disabling payment modules one by one.